# Remove part of a string before a certain position

Tags: javascript, indexing

I have a string I want to cut and remove the first part.

Something like  'abcded-cddndcasds--XYZ--jkajsjasasasasas'

I want to remove everything before  position X.

So far I can find the position of X, but can't find a quick function to remove everything before.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
   var str = 'abcded-cddndcasds--XYZ--jkajsjasasasasas';

   var indexOfX = str.indexOf("X");

   alert(str.substring(indexOfX,str.length));
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AJpSz/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and give the starting index and `substring()` will take string starting from given index to end of string.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yAL9T/)**

```
res = str.substring(str.indexOf('X'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'abcded-cddndcasds--XYZ--jkajsjasasasasas';
str = "X"+str.split('X')[1];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/JVZXG/)

Comment: This will do the wrong thing if there are two `X` in the string. The `substring()` answers are safer in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Every programming language offers standard methods in String API to achieve this thing:

a) `indexOf(X)` - find the first occurrence of given letter in the sentence.

b) `lastIndexOf(X)` - find the last occurrence of given letter in the sentence.

c) `substring(start index, end index)` - extracts the text based upon `start` and end `index` positions.

**Example:**

```
var str = "abcded-cddndcasds--XYZ--jkajsjasasasasas"
var index = str.indexOf("X");

if (index != -1)
   str.substring(str.indexOf("X"));
```

Hope this helps!